# c++ method to order a matrix by elements in a column (the same of sortrows in MATLAB)

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix

I'm looking for a c++ method that is able to order the rows of a matrix by a decreasing order of the values in a specific column.

For example, if this is my input:

```
matrix = [1,2,3;
          2,4,1;
          0,5,2]
```

the call of the method(matrix,3) should provide the following output:

```
outputMatrix = [1,2,3;
                0,5,2;
                2,4,1]
```

In MATLAB this can be done by the calling of the function:

```
outputMatrix = sortrows(matrix,3).
```

What about c++? (In both cases, 3 is the index of the column).

Moreover in the script I'm working, the matrix is defined as a vector of vector: `std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix`

**[EDIT]** I add another example:

```
input = [4,5,6;
         0,2,8;
         1,2,3;
         6,7,9]
```

outputMatrix = sortrows(input,2);
Column 2, ordered, is: 9,8,6,3; so I have to order the rows and copy the elements of the first two columns (respectively 0 and 1).

```
 outputMatrix = [6,7,9;
                 0,2,8;
                 4,5,6;
                 1,2,3]
```

I report here the method I wrote to do this, but I don't know if this is a fast way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > sortrows(std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix,int col){
    int length = matrix[col].size();
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > output(3,std::vector<double>(length*length));
    output[col] = matrix[col];
    std::sort(output[col].begin(),output[col].end(),std::greater<double>());
    for (int i = 0; i < length*length;i++){
        int index = 0;
        while(output[col][i]!=matrix[col][index]){index++;}
        output[0][i]=matrix[0][index];
        output[1][i]=matrix[1][index];
        matrix[2][index] = -1;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement a sort of something simple, like an array of int? Are you comfortable with `std::sort`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, anyway I'm a newbie on c++, I have read about the use of sort only for vectors and not matrices. In particular I don't know how to use the conditional function.

Comment: If you wish that someone write the function for you, ask a colleague. If you wish to learn to write it yourself, I advise you to start by implementing [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) on a small array of integers with pencil and paper. You must start with the simple and climb up to the complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like following (in C++11), sort the matrix rows based on a specific column

```
void sortrows(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix, int col) {    
    std::sort(matrix.begin(),
              matrix.end(),
              [col](const std::vector<double>& lhs, const std::vector<double>& rhs) {
                  return lhs[col] > rhs[col];
              });
}
```

Also notice, this code changes the original matrix rather than returning a new matrix.

non C++11 version:

```
class Compare {
public:
    Compare(int col) : col_(col) {}
    bool operator()(std::vector<double>& lhs, std::vector<double>& rhs) {
        return lhs[col_] > rhs[col_];
    }
private:
    int col_; 
};

void sortrows(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix, int col) {    
    std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), Compare(col));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, anyway I'm a newbie on c++. I don't understand if this is a method, in particular what do I have to do in order for use this code?

Comment: thanks again for your code. But this doesn't do what I need (as is shown in the example above). Maybe I'm not able to use the method in the right way. ;-)

Comment: as I said, it changs the original matrix, you can copy the matrix first, then mutate the copied one.

Comment: yes I have understood that. But what I'm saying is that: this method doesn't order the rows of a matrix by a decreasing order of the values in a specific column. It seems like it orders the column.

Comment: @Mattia, please give me another sample, since I already tested the sample you give. It's better to show how you use it. And notice in the example you give, you should call sortrows(matrix, 2), since index begins from 0 in C++

Comment: really thanks for your time and advices. I have edited the question adding another example. I also put a the code I wrote to do this method but I don't know if there are better or faster solution. Any advice? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
void SortRows(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& inputVector,int col)
{
    bool stay{true};
    for (int ii = 0; ii< inputVector.size();ii++)
    {
        if(stay)
        {
            stay = false;
            for(int jj=0;jj<inputVector.size()-1;jj++)
            {
                if(inputVector[jj][col] < inputVector[jj+1][col])
                {
                    inputVector[jj].swap(inputVector[jj+1]);
                    stay = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a bubble sort algorithm that solves your problem.

Notice that this algorithm changes the input with descending order due to '<' sign,
you can use '>' for ascending order.

If you have any hesitation, please ask again.